# How do I manipulate,modify excel files using python3 along with searching/sorting algorithms for huge databases?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlsx

I am new to python and need to work on a project with the whole database on excel. The database is over 100k entries and has to be periodically modified and searched/sorted often.

Are there any package(s) for this?

Comment: Are you sure excel is the correct way to go, instead of a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your title, this is a list of python modules that can perform various operations on Excel worksheets.

1. [Pandas](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) (possibly your best option, since it has powerful data management).
2. [pyExcelerator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyExcelerator/) (apparently not maintained anymore)
3. [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) (a fork of `pyExcelerator`)
4. [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)
5. [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)

As to search/sort, python has builtin features and there are plenty of other packages.

1. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/algorithms